# Mongoose find by id ignoring depth level

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema

```
const personSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  children: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
    required: false
  }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Inside children I can have another person object.
ex:

```
{ name: 'yoshi',
  id: 01,
  children: [
  { name: 'luigi',
    id: 02,
    children: []
  },
  { name: 'mario',
    id: 03,
    children: [
    { name: 'bowser',
      id: 04
      children: []
    }
  ]
```

If I only have 'bowser' ID (04), how to get 'bowser' object and it's children?

I try Person.findById(04), but I can't get it.
I only can get yoshi (01) using findById

Is there a way to ignore all level and focus only getting by ID?
I dont want to use find(children.children.id), because I have dynamic depth level.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic way for recursing nested structure for dynamic depth level. Consider refactoring your schema like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sU9cfT8bW5l) or using javascript to handle the recursive logic.

Comment: If I need to refractor it, How can i get the exact same structure as my initial schema? Name, id, children. Then inside children, I repeat the person object in array

Comment: Your initial schema with dynamic nesting depth would be hard to perform query on. It all depends on your use case. Why do you want to keep the dynamic nesting? Can it be replaced by the parent model in my previous comment? or the children model that support `$graphLookup` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/62pNZ5YboFO)?

Comment: Initially I design my D3.js diagram using yaml format to draw family tree. I need one big object that have children then children have children again until last generation family. In your last example using $graphLookup almost look like what I want, but your example have 2 object in separate result, 1. Yoshi children, 2. Mario children. What I really want is only yoshi object that have children, then inside children have children again

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to have no way to support querying on your requested structure as of now. You either need to change your family tree parsing logic or keeping the existing document structure and perform the query with some javascript to perform the recursive search.